# gRPC slow in sending 360MB message in testing local to local

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I am working under Windows 10, Python 3.6.8 64 bit, grpcio ver 1.40.0

I am new to gRPC. I am testing sending a message which contains 9 int32 fields and 10 numpy array fields coded as base64 strings. The sending of the meessage between client and server on the local machine (127.0.0.1) takes consitently 6.8 seconds for a message which is 360MB in size in total. This timing exludes any encodning, 6.8 seconds is solely for the RPC call which simply sends the data and where the encoded message is built ahead of the call.

I am puzzled by this result, as I was expecting something sub-second. Is this to be expected for gRPC? Most of that time, should be spent handling the message, rather than in the transmission, as this is a local to local test. Is this overhead normal? Is gRPC not a good library for large messages?

Thanks for any appreciaed comment,

Best Regards,

Andrea

Comment: Are you by chance on an M1 Mac? I’m having similar issues on mine…